# How to know if UWF is enabled or disabled

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwf, uwfmgr

How do I know if the UWF is enabled or disabled?
I'm making an application with C # so I need to know for that language.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to keep in mind when considering whether UWF is enabled or disabled:

1. Protection is not enabled when UWF is enabled, you need to exlicitly turn it ON by making use of Protect method in [UWF_Volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-volume) class.
2. A system reboot is required after enabling or disabling of UWF in order to apply the changes. [UWF_Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-filter) class provides methods for enable/disable and for performing reboot/shutdown of the system.

The C# code below demonstrates the use of **CurrentEnabled** property of UWF_Filter class:

```
public static bool IsEnabled()
    {
        try
        {
            //root\standardcimv2\embedded
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\standardcimv2\embedded");
            using (ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(scope.Path.Path, "UWF_Filter",
            null))
            {
                ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

                foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
                {
                    // Please make use of NextEnabled property in case you have enabled the UWF_Filter in the current session. 
                    //The value in CurrentEnabled is populated only when the UWF_Filter was enabled on system boot.
                    return (bool)mo.GetPropertyValue("CurrentEnabled");
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Note/Request**: Request someone with [1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) to create and link following tags so that it becomes easier for people like me to request solutions/answer questions on stackoverflow.

1. UWF
2. UWFMGR

Comment: Running as a non-admin user, I find that this works when the filter is disabled, but as soon as the filter is actually enabled, it returns with access denied...