# Is there a UWF dll?

Tags: c#, windows-10

I must use (enable and disable) the UWF in an application in Windows 10.
This is why I have to migrate the project from Windows 7 to Windows 10. The Win7's EWF functionality should turn it into UWF in Win10.
In the current project the colleague who had done it had used a dll (EWFProxy.XEWF.cs). Is there something similar to UWF?

```
public class XEWF : IDisposable
{
    public XEWF();

    public bool IsEWFInstalled { get; }
    public bool IsSystemProtected { get; }
    public List<string> ListVolumes { get; }

    public void Commit();
    public void Disable();
    public override sealed void Dispose();
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool value);
    public void Enable();
    public EWFCMD GetPendingCommand();
    public EWFSTATE GetState();
    public void Reset();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'll try to write a library for the same but please look at following two answers on stackoverflow: [UWF enabled or disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134026) and [UWF - Get registry exclusions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099258)

Comment: I know my answer is a bit late ;-): I created a small C# application some time ago (open source under MIT license), in which I enable and disable the UW filter via CIM (WMI), among other things. Maybe it helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no dll you have to/can import into your project. UWF has to be installed on the system.

The control can be fully done using

a) WMI (see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449332(v=winembedded.82).aspx)

or

b) the uwfmgr.exe which itself is only a wrapper for the WMI functions and classes.